# Fees , Reward and Staking in Near

Tags: nearprotocol

Can any one help me understand

1. What happens to the fees of each transactions ? Does fees become part of the reward ?
2. When does the reward gets distributed . Is there any specific timeperiod. Can you please point me to couple of examples in explorer where reward is distribuited.

i got this docs for Reward - https://nomicon.io/Economics/README.html#rewards-calculation

coinbaseReward[t]   The maximum inflation per epoch[t], as a function of REWARD_PCT_PER_YEAR / EPOCHS_A_YEAR

where can i get REWARD_PCT_PER_YEAR and EPOCHS_A_YEAR. Does it remain fixed for ceratin range of blocks

epochReward[t]  = coinbaseReward[t] + epochFee[t]

epochFee[t] - does this mean fees of all transactions happened in an epoch .

3. Can i have some staking transactions from explorer if any

Answer (score 1):

Sure,
I had exactly the same questions and came out with a [doc](https://github.com/telezhnaya/docs/blob/master/docs/tokens/balances.md).

In a few words:

1. Fees are burnt, they do not become a part of validators reward, though part of the fees of function calls and cross-contract function calls become a royalty reward to contract accounts.
2. Reward tokens are minted every epoch (something about every 12 hours) and gone to staking pools.
3. Please check the doc for the examples, I covered all possible situations of balance changing with all numbers and explanation what is going on.

UPD by the way, it's true, there is no information about royalties in Nomicon, we created [the issue](https://github.com/near/NEPs/issues/198) for that

Comment: Hi Olga i followed the doc and was looking at Receiving the reward for being validator section.Could you please help me with the apis how did you derive these information for block 32716252 and 32716253. I tried with api method block, chunk. The chunk method also provides 0 transactionHashes. Once i get these apis i can map the info and understand your findings better.

Comment: Hi Olga for "Delete Account" Operation i had to use 3 api calls to get the balance changing operations. GetBlockDetails-block,
GetChunkDetails- chunk,
GetTransactionStatusWithReceipts -EXPERIMENTAL_tx_status.
The Thrid method is with experimental tag , Is it supported in long term or am i calling the wrong apis to underdtand the balance changing operations

Comment: I mostly used `EXPERIMENTAL_tx_status` to collect this data. Yeah, it is marked as experimental, so no guarantee is given for future support of this call

Comment: Hi Olga , I tried to query the block - 32716252 using blovk method and i take the chunk hash from there but when i query the chunk method using chunk hash i get no transactions.Can you help me get the info you have presented in the doument